# why PHP skip my return command?

Tags: php, return, return-value, return-type

I wonder why does this happen. I have code like this (I put return just for debugging):

```
public function foo($var) {
    do_something_here;
    return 'stop';
    if ($var > 0)
    { return 'true'; }
    return 'false';
}
```

and what I get is my function doesn't stop at `return 'stop'` line as supposed (it still continue to return 'true' (or 'false' if it false). Does it mean that `return` command must be put on the end line of function (or in conditional statement)?

Comment: No it will return and not execute the rest of the code, https://3v4l.org/ZObXM

Comment: but in Laravel function I create something like that and then receive returned value in jQuery. And jQuery still read between true or false, not stop. sounds weird. @LawrenceCherone

Comment: your _do something here_  probably contains an if statement which prevent the function to stop at `return 'stop'`;

Comment: I clean my cache and now it's return stop as supposed. Can cache affect PHP script? @Elementary

Comment: yes it is possible.Some PHP applications use cache to avoid reloading to many times the same files .Some functions can be cached too so any modification will be reflected only after cache cleaning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I clean my browser cache and problem solved.